# I'm trying to put value into an array per second using CountDownTimer but it's not working

Tags: java, android, timer

```
public class Calculator {

float[] countPerSec = new float[600];
float[] finishedArray = new float[600];
float[] omegaArray = new float[600];
float[] sortedArray = new float[600];
int radius = 55;
float windSpeedArray[] = new float[600];
float windspeedAvg = 0;
float[] windspeedMinMax = new float[2];
int timerArrayCounter = 0;



int sensorCountValue = 20;  //**count per second returned by the sensor**




//this function will update x values from 0 to 599 per second
public float[] fetchPerSecValues(){


    new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            // while(timerArrayCounter == 59){
             Log.d("Timer","Running Clock");
                 countPerSec[timerArrayCounter++] = sensorCountValue;

                 String abc = Float.toString(countPerSec[timerArrayCounter]);
                 Log.d("Timer", abc);
            // }


         }

         public void onFinish() {

             for(int c = 0; c < 60; c++){
            finishedArray[c] = countPerSec[c];
            omegaArray[c] = (float) (finishedArray[c]*2*3.14);
            windSpeedArray[c] = radius*omegaArray[c]; 

              }


             Log.d("Here","Finished Clock");
                timerArrayCounter = 0;
                fetchPerSecValues();




         }
      }.start();
    return windSpeedArray;


}
```

The timer function runs but the value of `sensorCountValue` which is 20 is not put into the array every second. What is my mistake here?
Another thing is when I run the code without the timer i get `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception. Yet again, what's the mistake?
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is being put into the array, the problem is you are advancing the index while you insert, so your log statement is actually getting the next entry in the array:

```
             countPerSec[timerArrayCounter++] = sensorCountValue;

             String abc = Float.toString(countPerSec[timerArrayCounter]);
             Log.d("Timer", abc);
```

Look closely at the stack trace in the logcat output, it'll point you right to the array out of bounds exception.